React Native StatusBar is hidden but still showing whitespace
I have set StatusBar,
StatusBar.currentHeight = 0;
StatusBar.setHidden(true, 'none');

and this gives me,

I want to set header's height including status bar whitespace with Linear Gradient background as shown in above image header.
I have also tried https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/39362#issuecomment-2046783858 this solution but it does not work.

Hiding status bar won't work. You have to set activity to full-screen for archiving it. 


I also tried that and it also did not work, also manager told me that the app does not need to be in full-screen

You can change status bar colour white in that case. Or make it same as your Linear Gradient background colour. If that works.
